# Beginner question: Using Java stream to access data on nested data structure with customized class

Tags: java, java-stream

i am learning the stream today and encountered this problem below: i know this is a beginner question but i hope this can be helpful to ppl who first learn steam like me. so the problem is to do stream() operation on a students array that has many instant variables defined. including two customized variable address and MobileNumber. each student object can instantiate a list of Mobilenumber.

since we have a students array of student objects. how do i use stream to access the mobilenumber array inside each student object and then use filter to find the "3333" number? and 2nd question is how can i Get all student having both mobile number 1233 and 1234, appreciate the help!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamsGalore {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

Student student1 = new Student("Jayesh", 20, new Address("1234"),
    Arrays.asList(new MobileNumber("1233"), new MobileNumber("1234")));

Student student2 = new Student("Khyati", 20, new Address("1235"), Arrays
    .asList(new MobileNumber("1111"), new MobileNumber("3333"), new MobileNumber("1233")));

Student student3 = new Student("Jason", 20, new Address("1236"),
    Arrays.asList(new MobileNumber("3333"), new MobileNumber("4444")));

List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(student1, student2, student3);

/*****************************************************
 * Get all student having mobile numbers 3333.
 *****************************************************/
students.stream().filter(student -> student.getMobileNumbers()
        .stream().anyMatch(mobileNumber -> mobileNumber.getNumber().equals("3333")))
        .forEach(student -> student.getName());

     /*****************************************************
 * Get all student having mobile number 1233 and 1234
 *****************************************************/
List<String> studentWith1233And1234 = students.stream().filter(student -> student.getMobileNumbers()
        .stream().anyMatch(mobileNumber -> mobileNumber.getNumber().equals("1233")&& mobileNumber.getNumber().equals("1234")))
        .map(Student::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(studentWith1233And1234); 

    }
}



import java.util.List;

class TempStudent {
  public String name;
  public int age;
  public Address address;
  public List<MobileNumber> mobileNumbers;

  public TempStudent(String name, int age, Address address, List<MobileNumber> mobileNumbers)         {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
  }
}


class Student {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Address address;
  private List<MobileNumber> mobileNumbers;

  public Student(String name, int age, Address address, List<MobileNumber> mobileNumbers) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public List<MobileNumber> getMobileNumbers() {
    return mobileNumbers;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public void setMobileNumbers(List<MobileNumber> mobileNumbers) {
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address
        + ", mobileNumbers=" + mobileNumbers + '}';
  }
}



  class Address {
    private String zipcode;

    public Address(String zipcode) {
      this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
      return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
      this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }
  }


  class MobileNumber {
    private String number;

    public MobileNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
      return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are missing the definition of class `MobileNumber` in your code-example ... it can only be implicitly assumed that it has a getter `getNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, but probably won't compile (MobileNumber is not of type String) to apply **containsAll()** with a List of String:

```
    List<String> studentWith1233And1234 = students.stream()
            .filter(student -> student.getMobileNumbers().stream().map(MobileNumber::getNumber)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(List.of("1233", "1234")))
            .map(Student::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The predicate below would always be evaluated to `false`:

```
.anyMatch(mobileNumber -> mobileNumber.getNumber().equals("1233")
                       && mobileNumber.getNumber().equals("1234"))
```

because the same string could **not** be equal to more than one distinct value. For that reason, the solution you've listed is not viable.

Instead, you can use collect all the mobile numbers assosiated with a particular student into a `Set` and then apply [`Set.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) or [`Set.containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) depending on whether you need to check if a single value, or a group of values is present.

```
List<String> studentWith1233And1234 = students.stream()
    .filter(student -> student.getMobileNumbers().stream()
        .map(MobileNumber::getNumber)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .containsAll(List.of("1233", "1234")))
    .map(Student::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList for Java 16+
```

and

```
List<String> studentsWith3333 = students.stream()
    .filter(student -> student.getMobileNumbers().stream()
        .map(MobileNumber::getNumber)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .contains("3333"))
    .map(Student::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList for Java 16+
```

***Note:*** performance of `contains()` and `containsAll()` methods, which are defined by the `Collection` interface, depends on the implementation of a collection on which method is being invoked. If you have only a couple of elements in the collection the difference between an `ArrayList` and `HashSet` would be moderate, but if `Student` and `MobileNumber` are only dummy analogies and in fact you have lots of elements then the difference in performance would be significant.

Comment: Hi Alex! thanks for the quick answer!!! i did no realize List offers containsAll method at all which is super handy! i am curious is there any actual use case of nested stream()?

Comment: @LittleZoski Sorry, I've missed that `MobileNumber` is a custom type. Nested stream is indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

I simplify your model a bit for better reading (remove `Address` and `TempStudent`, use record for removing all getter/setter/toString/equals methods)

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student student1 = new Student("Jayesh", 20, Arrays.asList(new MobileNumber("1233"), new MobileNumber("1234")));
        
        Student student2 = new Student("Khyati", 20, Arrays.asList(new MobileNumber("1111"), new MobileNumber("3333"), new MobileNumber("1233")));
        
        Student student3 = new Student("Jason", 20, Arrays.asList(new MobileNumber("3333"), new MobileNumber("4444")));
        
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(student1, student2, student3);
        
        /*****************************************************
         * Get all student having mobile numbers 3333.
         *****************************************************/
        List<Student> studentsWith3333 =
                students.stream()
                        .filter(student -> student.containsNumber("3333"))
                        .toList();
        System.out.println("Get all students having mobile numbers 3333");
        System.out.println(studentsWith3333);
        
        /*****************************************************
         * Get all student having mobile number 1233 and 1234
         *****************************************************/
        List<Student> studentWith1233And1234 =
                students.stream()
                        .filter(student -> student.containsAllNumbers(List.of("1233","1234")))
                        .toList();
        System.out.println("Get all students having mobile numbers 1233 and 1234");
        System.out.println(studentWith1233And1234);
        
    }
    
    record MobileNumber(String number) {}
    
    record Student(String name, int age, List<MobileNumber> numbers) {
        
        boolean containsNumber(String number){
            return numbers.contains(new MobileNumber(number));
        }
    
        boolean containsAllNumbers(List<String> numberList){
            return numbers.containsAll(numberList.stream().map(MobileNumber::new).toList());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Get all students having mobile numbers 3333
[
   Student[
      name=Khyati, 
      age=20, 
      numbers=[
         MobileNumber[number=1111], MobileNumber[number=3333], MobileNumber[number=1233]
      ]
   ],
   Student[
      name=Jason,
      age=20,
      numbers=[
         MobileNumber[number=3333], MobileNumber[number=4444]
      ]
   ]
]
Get all students having mobile numbers 1233 and 1234
[
   Student[
      name=Jayesh, 
      age=20, 
      numbers=[
         MobileNumber[number=1233], MobileNumber[number=1234]
      ]
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Predicate` functional to filter.
This predicate can also be created from a `Set` of given numbers using a static (factory) method:

```java
// method to create a filter
static Predicate<Student> hasNumbers(Set<String> searchedNumbers) {
   return (student) -> Set.of(student.getMobileNumbers()).containsAll(searchedNumbers);
   // use a stream map to string for the Set-creation
   // if MobileNumber.getNumber() is the only getter
}


// either one number to search
var byNumber = hasNumbers(Set.of("3333"));
// or many numbers to search
var byNumbers = hasNumbers(Set.of("1233", "1234"));

// apply the filter for your case:
var foundNames = students.stream()
  .filter(byNumber)  // or use the other filter: byNumbers (plural)
  .map(Student::getName)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Benefits:

- the stream is short and readable
- the filter can be created by any given numbers on the fly